# Extra alignment tab changed to \cr in Longtable

Tags: longtable

I am trying to make this table but I am constantly getting this error

> "Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.
>    ... width\arrayrulewidth }\endtemplate "

I am using longtable because the table when full with content is likely to overflow the page.

```
   \documentclass{article} 
   \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
   \usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor} 
   \usepackage{multirow} 
   \usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
   \usepackage{tabularx} 
   \usepackage{longtable}
   \usepackage{array} 
   \geometry{a4paper,tmargin=3.5cm, bmargin=2.5cm, lmargin=1.5cm, rmargin=1.5cm, headheight=3em, headsep=1.5cm, footskip=1cm} 
   \usepackage{color, colortbl} 
   \definecolor{mColor1}{rgb}{0.9,0.9,0.9} 
   \usepackage{tgbonum} 
   \usepackage{pdflscape}

   \begin{document}   
   \renewcommand*\rmdefault{cmss}

   \centering
   \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}
   \setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1pt}
   \begin{longtable}
   {|p{\dimexpr.3\textwidth-2\tabcolsep} | p{\dimexpr.3\textwidth-2\tabcolsep} | p{\dimexpr.2\textwidth-2\tabcolsep} | p{\dimexpr.2\textwidth-2\tabcolsep} |}
   \caption{List of Subsidaries/JVs/AEs} 
   \hline 
   \rowcolor{mColor1} 
   \\Name & CIN/FCRN & Type of Company & \% of shares held\\ABC Inc. && FBSDKSNDNI24 && Associate Enterprise & 48\\\hline\end{longtable}

   \end{document}
```

Comment: you have  a 4 column table but have 0 cells in the first row, 4 in the second and 6 in the third. Did you intend `&` instead of `&&` ??

Comment: I am so sorry just noticed that. Should have noticed that, I feel embarrassed that I posted this here. Time to go to sleep now. Thank you!

Comment: no harm done:-)

Comment: I'm voting to close this because  it is just `&&` typo fixed via comments

Comment: @Mico oh no need to close now you've answered I just +1 your answer instead

Answer (score 3):

In addition to taking care of the most pressing issue -- replacing the two instances of `&&` with `&` -- you should also

- remove the `\\` line-breaking instruction at the beginning of the first row,
- add a `\\` instruction immediately after `\caption{...}`, and
- subtract an additional `1.25\arrayrulewidth` from the width of each of the four `p` columns. Since there are 5 vertical rules, their combined width is `5\arrayrulewidth`. Subtract one quarter of that amount, i.e., `1.25\arrayrulewidth`, from each of the column width directives.
- be systematic in the way you organize the table's header and footer information. Do use the `\endfirsthead`, `\endhead`, `\endfoot`, and `\endlastfoot` directives of the `longtable` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
%% I've commented out unneeded package-loading instructions
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor} 
%%\usepackage{multirow} 
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
%%\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array} 
\geometry{a4paper,tmargin=3.5cm, bmargin=2.5cm, lmargin=1.5cm, rmargin=1.5cm, headheight=3em, headsep=1.5cm, footskip=1cm} 
%%\usepackage{color, colortbl} 
\definecolor{mColor1}{rgb}{0.9,0.9,0.9} 
\usepackage{tgbonum} 
%%\usepackage{pdflscape}

\begin{document}   
\renewcommand\rmdefault{cmss}

%%%\centering % not needed
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1pt}
\begin{longtable}
{| p{\dimexpr.3\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1.25\arrayrulewidth\relax} 
 | p{\dimexpr.3\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1.25\arrayrulewidth\relax} 
 | p{\dimexpr.2\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1.25\arrayrulewidth\relax} 
 | p{\dimexpr.2\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1.25\arrayrulewidth\relax} |}

%% set up the table's header and footer structures
\caption{List of Subsidaries/JVs/AEs} \label{tab:list}\\
\hline 
\rowcolor{mColor1} 
Name & CIN/FCRN & Type of Company & \% of shares held\\
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{4}{l}{Table \ref{tab:list}, cont'd}\\
\hline
\rowcolor{mColor1} 
Name & CIN/FCRN & Type of Company & \% of shares held\\
\endhead
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{r}{(cont'd on following page)}\\
\endfoot
\hline
\endlastfoot

%% body of table
ABC Inc. & FBSDKSNDNI24 & Associate Enterprise & 48\\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I am from a non-technical background (law to be precise) and learning the ropes. Will definitely incorporate your suggestions. Once again thank you for showing me the correct way to go about it.